# Make vega-lite selection only take effect on mouseup

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I would like to have an interval selection in a Vega-lite in which other data is filtered in response to the selection, but only after the user releases the mouse. For instance, consider [this example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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) where the user can filter the dates in a time series plot by selecting a range on another chart. As the user drags the selection in the bottom chart the top chart filters in real-time. What I would like to do is instead have the top chart only filter once the user has updated the selection in the bottom chart and released the mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It seems a bit awkward to me but does what you ask.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/sp500.csv"},
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "width": 480,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "scale": {"domain": {"param": "brush"}},
          "axis": {"title": ""}
        },
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "width": 480,
      "height": 60,
      "mark": "area",
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "brush",
          "select": {
            "type": "interval",
            "encodings": ["x"],
            "on": {
              "type": "mousemove",
              "between": [{"type": "mouseup"}, {"type": "mousedown"}]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"tickCount": 3, "grid": false}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David, but I was looking for something a bit different. In your example when the user clicks and releases the mouse button they can then move the mouse to create the selection region, but while they are doing so the top chart is filtering. Likewise, after the selection is created you can click inside it and slide it side to side and the top chart will filter as you drag. What I was aiming for was behavior exactly like the original example, but for the top chart to not filter until after the user finishes defining the selection or finishes dragging an already created selection.

Comment: I'm not sure Vega has events to define when the actual filtering happens; it is all instant as far as I can see. You could try debounce but it is a bit clunky and not exactly what you're looking for.